# Haskell - priority of operations

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, operator-precedence

I'm trying to be clear with the precedence rules in Haskell.
When I write the line of code "f a b" it will be interpreted (f a) b ie with a left-associative mechanism.

But let's imagine that I am coding in Haskell a function calculating the terms of the fibonnaci sequence. I then run the following program:

```
fibo 0 = 1
fibo 1 = 1
fibo n = fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
```

For the last expression, this will be interpreted as :

```
(((fibo(n-1))+)fibo)(n-2))
```

Why there is no error when it fetches the second fibo. How does the compiler know that fibo must apply to (n-2) before the result is given as an argument to the function (+)? Is it related to arithmetic operators?

I try many tests on ghci and the syntax

```
g = fibo 2 + fibo
```

is not accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell makes a strong distinction between infix operator and prefix / nonfix (is that a word?) functions or variables.

- Anything containing only letters, underscores and/or non-leading numbers and beginning with either a lowercase letter or underscore is a *variable*. This includes simple function-arguments like `n` as well as normal prefix functions like `length` or `print` or `cos`. It is these functions for which the left-associative parsing rule applies.
- Anything containing non-letter/number codepoints is an infix operator. These are parsed completely different, namely the always bind weaker than function application, they bind things on both sides of the operator, and they have their own precedence hierarchy.

For your example, the `+` operator is the only infix that's not in parentheses, so the parsing starts by separating the subexpressions on each side of it.

```
fibo n = ░ + ░
```

Only then does it parse the prefix applications, like

```
fibo n =    ░    +     ░
        ┌───┴───┐  ┌───┴───┐
        fibo(n-2)  fibo(n-2)
```

Same thing of course with the inner expressions:

```
fibo n =     ░     +      ░
        ┌────┴────┐  ┌────┴────┐
        fibo(░ - ░)  fibo(░ - ░)
            ┌┴┐ ┌┴┐      ┌┴┐ ┌┴┐
             n   1        n   2
```

Comment: Pretty diagrams. Done by hand, or do I get to add a new tool to my life?

Comment: @DanielWagner only [`.S`, `dr`, `hh`, `uh`, and `dl`](https://vimhelp.org/digraph.txt.html).

Answer (score 6):

> For the last expression, this will be interpreted as :
>
> ```
> (((fibo(n-1))+)fibo)(n-2))
> ```

That's simply incorrect.

---

Function application has higher precedence than *any* operator.

```
fibo (n - 1) + fibo (n - 2)
```

is equivalent to

```
(fibo (n - 1)) + (fibo (n - 2))
```

Note that the parentheses are *not* part of the function call syntax; the expression

```
fibo n - 1
```

is still a function application, but it subtracts 1 from the result of `fibo n`, the same as `(fibo n) - 1`.